# using EXCEPT or INTERSECT to only show mismatched rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have 2 result sets (2 queries).

```
FIELDNAME   VALUE
field1      20.00
field2      13.00
field3      4.00

FIELDNAME   VALUE
field1      20.00
field2      14.00
field3      6.00
```

I know `query1 EXCEPT query2` should give

```
FIELDNAME   VALUE
field2      13.00
field3      4.00
```

But what I really want is to show any cases where there is a difference, from both sides of the query:

```
FIELDNAME   VALUE
field2      13.00
field3      4.00
field2      14.00
field3      6.00
```

Is that possible?  I suppose I could do a SELECT UNION into a temp table.  Then delete any rows where NOT EXISTS fieldname with different value.  Anything simpler?

It seems like I could combine the INTERSECT, UNION and EXCEPT somehow and end up with this, but not having much luck conceptualizing.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should be able to get what you need by using `EXCEPT` twice and using `UNION ALL` on the results:

```
-- records from the table1 that are not in table2
(SELECT * FROM table1 
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM table2)

UNION ALL

-- records from the table2 that are not in table1
(SELECT * FROM table2 
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM table1)
```

Other approach is to get combination of all tables using `UNION`, then use `EXCEPT` to eliminate all intersecting records:

```
-- Union of both tables
(SELECT * FROM table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2)

EXCEPT   -- Exclude the records ...

-- ... that are in both tables
(SELECT * FROM table1 
INTERSECT 
SELECT * FROM table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's like [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operation:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(Name nvarchar(20), Value decimal)
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(Name nvarchar(20), Value decimal)

INSERT INTO @Table1 
VALUES
(N'field1', 20.00),
(N'field2', 13.00),
(N'field3',  4.00)


INSERT INTO @Table2 
VALUES
(N'field1', 20.00),
(N'field2', 14.00),
(N'field3',  6.00)


SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @Table1 AS t
    EXCEPT (SELECT * FROM @Table2 AS t)
) AS a
UNION
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @Table2 AS t
    EXCEPT (SELECT * FROM @Table1 AS t)
) AS b
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your post, you already tried with INTERSECT, UNION and EXCEPT combination but not get the output.

Try like this using (INTERSECT, UNION and EXCEPT) to get it.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(Name nvarchar(20), Value decimal(18,2))
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(Name nvarchar(20), Value decimal(18,2))

INSERT INTO @Table1 
VALUES
(N'field1', 20.00),
(N'field2', 13.00),
(N'field3',  4.00)


INSERT INTO @Table2 
VALUES
(N'field1', 20.00),
(N'field2', 14.00),
(N'field3',  6.00)

select *From @Table1
union
select *From @Table2
except
select *From @Table1
intersect
select *From @Table2
```